# Summations zu.mpfr and zstar based on a probability sample

Tags: performance, r

Here is my code:

```
library(gtools)
library(Rmpfr)
library(OBsMD)
precBits=1000000
K=9
n=1000
p=mpfr(c(K:1),precBits = precBits);p=mpfr(p,precBits = precBits)/mpfr(sum(p),precBits = precBits)
#p is a vector of probabilities

zu.mpfr <- function(freq, u, precBits){
  sum=mpfr(0,precBits = precBits)
  n=sum(freq)
  for (i in (1:length(freq))){
    prod=mpfr(1,precBits = precBits)
    for (j in (0:(u-1))){
      prod=prod*(mpfr(freq[i]-j,precBits = precBits))/mpfr(n-j,precBits=precBits)
    }
    sum=sum+prod
  }
  return(sum)
}

etastar<-rep(mpfr(0,precBits = precBits),K-1)
etastar=c(etastar)
for (i in 1:(K-1)){
  etastar[i]=sum(p^mpfr(i+1,precBits))
}
```

In the above codes, `p` is a vector of probabilities. `zu.mpfr` is \$z_u =\sum_k \prod_{j=0}^{u-1}\frac{Y_k-j}{n-j},\$ where \$u\$ can be any positive integer (but no more than \$n\$), and \$Y_k\$ is the observed frequency in a random sample for catagory \$k\$. The inputs for `zu.mpfr` are the sample frequency counts, \$u\$, and `precBits` (the preset accuracy). For the frequency, for example, if a sample is \$\{1,1,2,3,3,3,4\}\$, then the corresponding frequencies are \$\{2,1,3,1\}\$, since observation "1" appears twice, "2" appears once, "3" appears three times, and "4" appears once. The frequency is directly generated by `rmultinom` in the next paragraph of codes. `etastar` is a vector of length \$K-1\$. And the \$i\$-th element, \$\eta^{*}(i)\$, is \$\sum_k p_k ^{i+1}.\$ As a summary, `zu.mpfr` is a value calculated from a random sample, and `etastar` is a vector calculated from the probability distribution `p`.

Following is the part that I need to make it faster:

```
start.time<-Sys.time()
sample=rmultinom(1,n,asNumeric(p))
zstar<-rep(mpfr(0,precBits = precBits),K-1)
zstar=c(zstar)
for(i in 1:(K-1)){
  zstar[i]=zu.mpfr(sample,i+1,precBits)
}

end_time <- Sys.time()
end_time-start.time
```

In the latter codes, I used `rmultinom` to get the `sample`, which is the frequency counts from a random sample that generated by the probability distribution `p`. Then I calculated `zstar`, which is a vector of length \$K-1\$, with the \$i\$-th element `zu.mpfr(sample, i+1, precBits)`. Here comes my problem. It takes too long to calculate the vector `zstar`. By timing it, "Time difference of 6.207007 secs" on my end. I am wondering if I can make it better. I need it faster because I need to run the simulation with thousands of iterations. I am not sure if the slowness is caused by `mpfr` but I do need it to enforce accuracy.

Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First suggestion would be to write a function for the high precision conversion because you keep using `mpfr(..., precBits = precBits)` over and over:

```
Z <- function(x) mpfr(x, precBits = 1000000)
```

It won't make your code faster but it will save you a lot of typing and make it easier on the eye.

Next, if you do not know why your code is slow, you need to learn to use the profiler:

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
[INSERT_YOUR_CODE_HERE]
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)
unlink(tmp)
```

It will show you that 90% of the time is spent doing the division in your `prod = prod * ...` line of code. So a solution would be to compute the numerator (`num`) and denominator (`den`) by iteration, then do a single division at the end:

```
zu.mpfr <- function(freq, u) {
  tot <- Z(0)
  n <- sum(freq)
  for (i in seq_along(freq)) {
    num <- Z(1)
    den <- Z(1)
    for (j in (0:(u-1))) {
      num <- num * Z(freq[i] - j)
      den <- den * Z(n - j)
    }
    prod <- num / den
    tot <- tot + prod
  }
  return(tot)
}
```

This alone makes your code three to four times faster.

Next, I would recommend looking for places where you can vectorize. I understand that your code is dealing with high precision numbers so maybe there is no other way than using for loops if only the simple operators (`+`, `*`, `/`) are available... However, it appears that if `x` is a vector of mpfr numbers, `prod(x)` also returns a mpfr number so I am ready to trust it is doing the right thing. If so, then you could do:

```
zu.mpfr <- function(freq, u) {
  tot <- Z(0)
  n <- sum(freq)
  J <- 0:(u-1)
  for (i in seq_along(freq)) {
    tot <- tot + prod(Z(freq[i] - J)) / prod(Z(n - J))
  }
  return(tot)
}
```

Have you noticed that we are computing the same denominator over and over? Move it outside the loop to save a little more:

```
zu.mpfr <- function(freq, u) {
  tot <- Z(0)
  n <- sum(freq)
  J <- 0:(u-1)
  den <- prod(Z(n - J))
  for (i in seq_along(freq)) {
    tot <- tot + prod(Z(freq[i] - J)) / den
  }
  return(tot)
}
```

Last, if memory size is not an issue (i.e. `K` remains small), you could save even more time by working with matrices. It's a bit harder to digest (including the computation of row-wise cumulative products), but it's elegant how short your code becomes (notice we don't need `zu.mpfr` anymore). This version is 5 to 6 times faster than your original one:

```
  sample <- c(rmultinom(1, n, asNumeric(p)))
  x <- Z(outer(sample, 0:(K-1), FUN = "-"))
  y <- Z(sum(sample) - 0:(K-1))
  z <- apply(x, 1, cumprod) / cumprod(y)
  zstar <- tail(rowSums(z), -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

After some testing, I would suggest that you decrease the `precBits`, because that changes a lot:

```
precBits = 10000
```

I did not see any (significant) changes in results using 10000.

Also, you can try this function, which uses one less loop and could be faster for larger K values:

```
FUN2 <- function(freq, u, precBits) {
  sum = mpfr(0, precBits = precBits)
  n = sum(freq)
  prod = mpfr(1, precBits = precBits)
  j <- (0:(u - 1))
  for (i in (1:length(freq))) {
      v1 <- mpfr(freq[i] - j, precBits = precBits)
      v2 <- mpfr(n - j, precBits = precBits)
      prod = prod(v1 / v2)
      sum = sum + prod
    }
  return(sum)
}
zstar2 <- rep(mpfr(0, precBits = precBits), K - 1)
for (i in 1:(K - 1)) {
  zstar2[i] = FUN2(sample, i + 1, precBits)
}
all.equal(zstar, zstar2) == T
zstar - zstar2
```

or this without loops:

```
FUN4 <- function(freq, u, precBits) {
  n = sum(freq)
  j <- (0:(u - 1))
  xx <- t(apply(freq, 1, function(x) x - j))
  v1 <- mpfr(xx, precBits = precBits)
  v2 <- mpfr(n - j, precBits = precBits)
  xx <- v1 / v2
  prods <- apply(xx, 1, prod)
  s <- sum(prods)
  return(s)
}
```

I suggest that you try them out with different `precBits` values and compare the results.

Comment: zstar calculated by FUN2 gives Time difference of 6.88253 secs. zstar calculated by FUN4 gives Time difference of 6.701213 secs. I am using that much precBits because of the accuracy requirements for other parts of my codes (not in here). I will try to reduce it to see how much it would affect. Under the current setting of precBits, is it possible to calculate my zstar vector faster?